# I had an enjoyable night or I have an enjoyable night

Tags: tense, past-tense

When receiving text from a friend the next day after a dinner.
I replied "Thank you for your invitation.  I had an enjoyable night."
Or should I reply "I have an enjoyable night"

Comment: If it happened in the past, it should be *had*.

Comment: [receiving **a** text from a friend]

Answer (score 1):

"I have an enjoyable............" is the present simple tense and implies you do this sort of thing on a regular basis and always enjoy it. It does not describe a one-time event in the past..

"I play darts every Friday evening at the pub, and I have an enjoyable night."

"I played darts last Friday evening at the pub, and I had an enjoyable night."

Comment: Would have had an enjoyable night be appropriate too?

Comment: No, that would be implying you did not have an enjoyable night because something prevented you from enjoying the event.  "I would have had an enjoyable night were it not for the dreadful company you keep, or the food was terrible, etc.

Comment: @BruceMurray Not necessarily. One could say  "Thank you very much for inviting me, I have had an enjoyable night". But one would normally use "have had" only if it was in the immediate past - e.g. just leaving a party

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the next day after the night so, this night is in the past.

You should say "*I had an enjoyable night*".